# Fulton, Exercise 2.28: Show that $R$ is a DVR.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

We define as order function on a field $K$ a function $\varphi$ from $K$ onto $\mathbb{Z}\cup \{\infty\}$ satisfying:
(I) $\varphi(a)=\infty$ if and only if $a=0$ 
(II) $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)$
(III) $\varphi(a+b)\ge \min\{\varphi(a),\varphi(b)\}$
We want to show that
$$R=\{z\in K\mid \varphi(z)\ge 0\}$$
is a DVR with maximal ideal
$$\mathfrak{m}=\{z\in K\mid \varphi(z)
> 0\}.$$
I proved that $R$ is a domain, that $z\in U(R)$ iff $\varphi(z)=0$ and that $\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal of $R$. So $R$ is local with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. But I can't show that $R$ is not field. I tried to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is not trivial, it doesn't help.
By the equivalent conditions of DVRs I tried find an irreducible element $t$ of $R$ such that for every non zero element $z$ in $R$, exists $u\in U(R)$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$: $z=ut^n$, but also in this cases must show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is not trivial for the existence of this $t$.
Could you help me to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is not trivial ideal of $R$?

Comment: You need to assume that the valuation is non-trivial.

Comment: To be more precise: you need to assume that there exists $a \in K$ with $\varphi(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be an element of $\mathfrak{m}$ with least valuation. If $v(\alpha) <\infty$, then this is a good candidate for $t$. Otherwise, $\alpha =0$.